# If statement inside switch (PHP)

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce, switch-statement

I'm working with WooCommerce and I am trying to develop a way to perform price calculation based in two factors:

- location of the customer by city
- category

I was able to change price based on the location of the customer but if I try to filter by location and category at the same time it does not work. To perform the filter by category I add this if statement:

```
if( has_term( array('nike'), 'product_cat' ,$product->ID) )
```

But I don't understand why this does not work.

**Here is the code**:

```
$userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
$countryCode = $userInfo->city->name;

switch ($countryCode) {
    case 'Madrid':
        if (has_term(array('nike') , 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
            add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2);
            function product_custom_price($price, $product) {
                $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                return $custom_price * 1.5;
            }
        }

        break;

    case 'Barcelona':
        if (has_term(array('adidas') , 'product_cat', $product->ID)) {
            add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2);
            function product_custom_price($price, $product) {
                $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                return $custom_price * 1.25;
            }
        }

        break;
}
```

Comment: are you getting any error ? please mention the error as well

Answer (score 0):

You are using `has_term` in wrong way and you can use foreach instead

Try this:

```
 $userInfo = geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip();
    $countryCode = $userInfo->city->name;
    $terms = get_the_terms($product->ID, 'product_cat');
                switch ($countryCode) {
                case 'Madrid':
          foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            if($term->name == 'nike') {
                   add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2);
                   function product_custom_price($price, $product) {
                 $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                 return $custom_price * 1.5;}
                                }
                    }

                break;
                case 'Barcelona':

           foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               if($term->name == 'adidas') {
                   add_filter('woocommerce_get_price', 'product_custom_price', 10, 2);
                    function product_custom_price($price, $product) {
                     $custom_price = $product->get_regular_price();
                      return $custom_price * 1.25;}
                                    }
                    }        

                break;

}
```

Comment: Are you completely sure posting a code without ANY explanation will benefit the OP?

Comment: @walther: I dont think it need explanation though I edited!

Comment: Thanks for your response but the code provided does not work , any other suggestion will be appreciated.Below i paste the code that use to change the price but i´´m not able to make if statement work together.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining separate functions for every combination of geolocation and category you can think of, and hardcoding this information, might I recommend storing it in your database?

Your code can quickly get unwieldy and very large with your current approach, especially once you consider that you're just multiplying by a constant all prices for a certain combination of `{category, country}`. What if you made a database table with these records (example code for mySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `pricing` (INT id, INT categoryID, CHAR(2) country, 
DOUBLE multiplier) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1
```

Country can hold 2-character ISO codes like 'US' or 'UK'. CategoryID holds whatever the ID of the category is in your category table, and multiplier holds values to increase or decrease prices, e.g. '1.5' or '1.25' for your two examples.

Then your `product_custom_price($price, $product)` function can simply do the following:

1. Figure out the category for the product from the products table
2. Use geoIP to detect the country code
3. Query the pricing table to get the multiplier.
4. Multiply the default price with this multiplier.

And you can just forward a this function to add_filter instead.
Altering the rules for the pricing doesn't involve having to modify any code, you can simply alter or add database records, so long as the pricing rules fit in the same pattern.

One little security thing: You should not use the result of `geoip_detect2_get_info_from_current_ip` to determine the actual amount of money you're going to charge someone. The ip is essentially untrusted input, so you would have to use wherever the customer wants you to deliver the product for the 'actual' calculation, or at least verify it's in the country your ip function returned. Using geoip for display purposes seems fine to me though.